# Remote Validation with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've just been reading the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx#Y2128) on MSDN about remote validation.  This is great, but it only shows validating a specific property value.

Is there a way I can pass other values from my model into the validation for a particular property? For example, let's say that a user wants to cancel a number of items off an order - they should be prevented from entering a figure greater than the original order amount.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

> Brad Wilson:
>
> At this time, only property level
>   validators can emit client-side
>   validation (as that lines up much
>   better with the idea of input
>   validation in the form of the
>   browser... there is no "model" to
>   speak of, from the browser's point of
>   view).
>
> Stuart Leeks:
>
> I don't believe you can hook up client
>   validation with IValidatableObject

Comment: Perhaps I'm approaching this problem from the wrong angle.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I imagine that you have a TextBox where user should type in a number. If you are using a 'numeric' control than check if it supports MaxValue. If this is a plain input than render a validation javascript yourself then you render the page and know current number of items.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jakub.  This will be a textbox as the value will vary greatly (from 1 to 10,000).  I was hoping to avoid a solution that involved client-side validation and was trying to keep all this logic on the server - that was the original intension of looking at the Remote attribute, but I now understand that this isn't possible the way I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i am nit sure if you mean this, but you can use AdditionalFields with your RemoteValidation attribute.

[Remote Validation in ASP.Net MVC 3: How to use AdditionalFields in Action Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752877/remote-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-additionalfields-in-action-method)