# Validating an object exists when editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is extremely silly, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I want to validate that an Employee username doesn't already exist when adding or editing an Employee. Here's my view model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Remote("UsernameExists", "Employees", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public ActionResult UsernameExists(string username)
{
    return Json(!_employeesRepository.UsernameExists(username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The function in the employee repository:

```
public bool UsernameExists(string username)
{
    return Employees.Where(e => e.Username.ToLower().Equals(username.ToLower())).Count() > 0;
}
```

This works great when I'm **creating** an Employee. But if I'm **editing** one and I try to save it, I get an error that the username already exists (which is true). So I need to somehow tell the function that it's okay the username exists if I'm editing an Employee with that username.

Is this possible with remote validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a extra flag to indicate what mode you're in, e.g. `bool isEditMode` and based on that, tweak your results. You can use AdditionalFields attribute to pass in that info; Also, take a look here: [Remote Validation in ASP.Net MVC 3: How to use AdditionalFields in Action Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752877/remote-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-additionalfields-in-action-method)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using two different viewmodels in which you derive the one from the other: the superclass can be used for editing, the subclass is for inserts with remote validation.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel // The normal one, can be used for editing
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
}

public class InsertEmloyeeViewModel : EmployeeViewModel
{
    [Remote("UsernameExists", "Employees", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists")]
    public override string Username { get; set; }

}
```

When the edit-functionlity also contains some 'specialities', you could derive a third class 'EditEmployeeViewModel' from the base class EmployeeViewmodel.