# Make client-side and server-side validation rules the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, client-side-validation, server-side-validation

I have an application who use ASP.NET MVC and KnockoutJS for the MVVM part.
The server bind the data to the server by JSON.
The client treat data and make a standard POST callback after that.

I have now to handle some business logic like :

- The property1 must be superior to  10  if property2 == "FOOBAR"
- The property2 must be != ""

Etc etc... (there is a lot of conditions I have to handle)

So, to make things simpler, is it possible to avoid code duplicate between the server side code (C#) and the client side (JS) ?
The idea would be to define the validation rules at one place (using Data Annotations maybe) and use these rules to generate the JS code (for client side validation) or the C# code (for the server side validation).

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that the [built in annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) combined with adding jQuery validation would suit most of your business requirements.

For example, your second one can be achieved using `[Required]`

For the ones that require something a little extra (like the first scenario you mentioned), you could either take a look at [`Remote` validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752877/remote-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-additionalfields-in-action-method) **or** implement your own annotations (but that gets a little trickier when hooking into jQuery validation to add your new annotations).

Comment: In fact, for the Required elements parts, with some code reflection, I could get the list of the properties name with [Required] and, by sending it to Knockout, I can get the fields required on the client based on the server annotations logic.

I never heard of Remote validation, I think for using same validation logic from client or server, it could be great !

But, in what implementing new annotations can help me with my problem ?

Comment: @eka808 Yeah. As for your own annotations, it can be done, but it's messier than Remote Validation as you'd have to implement things into jquery validation to handle your new attributes.

Comment: And what about, before doing the final submit, make a POST query with the client entity to an action called, for example, ValidateModel, who will return the models error casted as JSON or true if all is ok ?
With this, I can use the server validation rules from the client.
What do you think ?

Comment: @eka808 Sounds reasonable, then you could loop through and display them (if needed).